# C program for Webcam capture

Tags: c, ubuntu, webcam-capture

I'm writing a simple C code for taking capture from my webcam and save it as a jpeg file on Ubuntu.
Here is the code used :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #define SIZE 76800 // number of pixels (320x240 for my webcam)
 int main() {
    FILE *camera, *grab;
    camera=fopen("/dev/video0", "rb");
    grab=fopen("grab.jpeg", "wb");
    float data[SIZE];
    fread(data, sizeof(data[0]), SIZE, camera);
    fwrite(data, sizeof(data[0]), SIZE, grab);
    fclose(camera);
    fclose(grab); 
    return 0;
 }
```

The resulting file is not a jpeg, how can I modify my code to obtain jpeg or png file at the end ?

Comment: Would you consider using OpenCV?

Comment: I can hardly imagine that there could be a mapping of 1 float representing 1 pixel. You write raw data (whatever format that might be). If you want to create a specific file format you should look at the specs for that format or use some graphics library

Comment: I would suggest you read something about V4L2. But a rough guess is, you webcam is USB UVC based which is usually MJPEG or YUV422 image format, and is usually a video stream rather than a single still image.

Answer (score 5):

This won't work. Because camera is a complex device and you have to set resolution, color scheme and some other important data to start capture.

You should use something like libuvc.

https://ken.tossell.net/libuvc/doc/group__device.html

You can check here. In line 614 they are trying to find a device and use it for camera grabbing. I think it's a great example.

https://github.com/gadLinux/OpenHMD-RiftPlayground/blob/master/src/main.c

Basically you have to init context, find camera, and use it.